# CropActivity doesn't open after picking image

Tags: java, android, image, crop

I tired to do same as in https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/crop-image-android-tutorial/. Pick image from gallary and after crop it. But when i'm included it to my fragment it's open gallary but after doesn't show crop activity. But when i did the same directly in activity its work!

My fragment onViewCreated

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SetupUI(view);
        SetupProfile();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();
        FragmentAdapterProfile adapter = new FragmentAdapterProfile(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        // Set the adapter onto the view pager
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.profileTabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("About");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Setting");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText("Post");
        changeavatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    onSelectImageClick(v);
            }
        });
    }
```

The picking

```
public void onSelectImageClick(View view) {
        CropImage.startPickImageActivity((Activity) context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // handle result of pick image chooser
        if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(context, data);

            // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage.
            if (CropImage.isReadExternalStoragePermissionsRequired(context, imageUri)) {
                // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
                mCropImageUri = imageUri;
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            } else {
                // no permissions required or already grunted, can start crop image activity
                startCropImageActivity(imageUri);
            }
        }

        // handle result of CropImageActivity
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                avatar.setImageURI(result.getUri());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Cropping successful, Sample: " + result.getSampleSize(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Cropping failed: " + result.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (mCropImageUri != null && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // required permissions granted, start crop image activity
            startCropImageActivity(mCropImageUri);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Cancelling, required permissions are not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start crop image activity for the given image.
     */
    private void startCropImageActivity(Uri imageUri) {
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setMultiTouchEnabled(true)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start((Activity) context);
    }
```

Comment: Might have something to do with Context of an activity vs a fragment, an Activity can receive a result.

Comment: Do they have difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i sloved this problem do the next.
I just created secondary Activity (empty) and call crop function in activity after it's work. Problem was in Contexts and Actvities.